# ruby on rails before save update another table first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, before-save

I am trying to update another associated table before saving but i am getting into errors i am not familiar with...

so i have in my model

**post.rb**

```
  before_save :update_total_items

  def update_total_items
    b = Tags.find(:tag_id => self.tag_id)
    b.total_items = b.total_items+1
    b.save
  end
```

but i get an error

```
Unknown key tag_id
```

so how can i access the property i am adding before i save it in order to use it and update an existing associated on another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the `id` of a model is called just that. Generally what you want is:

```
b = Tags.find(self.tag_id)
```

Be aware this might throw an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception if no record could be found. A safer approach is:

```
if (b = Tags.where(:id => self.tag_id).first)
  b.increment!(:total_items)
end
```

Avoid loading and saving to increment a value. You may end up with an ugly race condition where you lose counts.

As a note, it's highly irregular that your model is called `Tags`. It should be called `Tag`.

Answer (score 1):

The Post object does not have a foreign key tag_id, change it to

```
  b = self.tags.find(:post_id => self.id)
```

This is assuming Post has_many :tags , and Tag belongs_to :post

and I agree with @tadman that you should use the increment method, 
 increment(attribute, by = 1)